# Text isn't scaling properly in frame

Tags: ios, swift, text, core-graphics

I'm making a *flowchart* app and I've ran into a problem while scaling shapes containing text in them.

Depending on the scale value the relative width of string changes:

scale 6.0: [scale 6.0](https://i.ibb.co/024vCQW/Screenshot-2019-08-10-at-15-53-14.png)
scale 1.0:
[scale 1.0](https://i.ibb.co/p3xqgTn/Screenshot-2019-08-10-at-15-51-24.png)
scale 0.5:
[scale 0.5](https://i.ibb.co/5BGKNbf/Screenshot-2019-08-10-at-15-54-19.png)

Text area class has property logFontSize, which represents constant font size (12.0 in this case).

Scaling function (zoomVal is the new scale):

```
func zoom(zoomVal: CGFloat){
    let newSize = self.logFontSize*zoomVal
    self.attributes![NSAttributedString.Key.font] = (self.attributes![NSAttributedString.Key.font] as! UIFont).withSize(newSize)
    self.attributedString?.setAttributes(self.attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.text!.count))
}
```

I've also checked: there is no correlation between scale value and relation between frame rectangle (red) height and string height (capHeight, lineHeight etc).

How do I scale text so that the relation between its width and its frame's width remains constant?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that improves legibility. Text metrics like size and padding do not have simple, linear relationships. They are tweaked in numerous ways at various sizes, and in font-specific ways, to keep text easy to read.

If you want to linearly scale text, you should render it, and then scale the layer it is drawn in. For your use case, likely the best approach would be to compose a static CATextLayer with CAShapeLayers, and then apply a CAAffineTransform to the entire container CALayer to resize it. This will give you smooth zooming, and will be more performant.